# Connect Fax voice modem

Tags: windows-xp, modem, fax

I'm doing a job in an IT company as a telecom operator.

One of my bosses asked me to connect his Fax voice modem for the Fax services, as well as to use POTS services through it. Actually I haven't seen this kind of network earlier and don't have any idea on how to do this.

How can I connect a modem to a PC and for the telephone line?

Answer (score 0):

Fax works over POTS, just connect the modem's RJ11 connector to a POTS phone outlet. If the modem is external (not an internal PCI card), you'll need to connect it to the PC using an appropriate serial cable (USB or RS232)

Here's an example connection diagram from the manual for a currently available external voice/fax/data modem.

[image: diagram]

And here's how you would connect a low-cost USB modem that also supports Fax

[image: photo of usb modem attached to laptop]

The details depend on the specific modem you will be using.